# Motion Path is down scaled

Tags: path, scale

linked a character
down scaled the character
Proxified the rig
The calculated motion path of the foot (or any other bone) appears to be down scaled

is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: There’s too little info here. Best to provide examples, screenshots, etc. One thing that springs to mind is that it possibly sounds like a scaing issue. Have you tried ‘Apply Scale’ on your character and/or rig?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.